# opencv can't open file: /storage/emulated/0/test.mp4 in virtual void cv::videostab::{anonymous}::VideoFileSourceImpl::reset()

Tags: android, opencv

I want to use `opencv-videostab` to improve video stability on `android` device. I have run the code successfully by using `NDK`，but when I try to use the `VideoFileSource` to read the file,it is not working but the throwing
below error.

```
cv::error(): OpenCV(3.4.2-dev) Error: No Error (can't open file: /storage/emulated/0/test.mp4) in virtual void cv::videostab::{anonymous}::VideoFileSourceImpl::reset(), file /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/videostab/src/frame_source.cpp, line 71
```

But the file actually exits and has got the necessary the permissions.
Can anyone help me find out the issue here. This is very important to me.

My cpp source code:

```
stability(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,jstring inputPath, jstring outputPath) {

    Ptr<IFrameSource> stabilizedFrames;

    const char *input = env->GetStringUTFChars(inputPath, NULL);
    const char *output = env->GetStringUTFChars(outputPath, NULL);

    string a = input;
    try {
        Ptr<VideoFileSource> source = makePtr<VideoFileSource>(input);
        cout << "frame count (rough): " << source->count() << endl;

        double min_inlier_ratio = 0.1;
        Ptr<MotionEstimatorRansacL2> est = makePtr<MotionEstimatorRansacL2>(MM_AFFINE);
        RansacParams ransac = est->ransacParams();
        ransac.size = 3;
        ransac.thresh = 5;
        ransac.eps = 0.5;
        est->setRansacParams(ransac);
        est->setMinInlierRatio(min_inlier_ratio);

        int nkps = 1000;
        Ptr<GFTTDetector> feature_detector = GFTTDetector::create(nkps);

        Ptr<KeypointBasedMotionEstimator> motionEstBuilder = makePtr<KeypointBasedMotionEstimator>(
                est);
        motionEstBuilder->setDetector(feature_detector);
        Ptr<IOutlierRejector> outlierRejector = makePtr<NullOutlierRejector>();
        motionEstBuilder->setOutlierRejector(outlierRejector);
        StabilizerBase *stabilizer = 0;
        bool isTwoPass = 1;
        int radius_pass = 15;
        if (isTwoPass) {
            bool est_trim = true;
            TwoPassStabilizer *twoPassStabilizer = new TwoPassStabilizer();
            twoPassStabilizer->setEstimateTrimRatio(est_trim);
            twoPassStabilizer->setMotionStabilizer(makePtr<GaussianMotionFilter>(radius_pass));
            stabilizer = twoPassStabilizer;
        } else {
            OnePassStabilizer *onePassStabilizer = new OnePassStabilizer();
            onePassStabilizer->setMotionFilter(makePtr<GaussianMotionFilter>(radius_pass));
            stabilizer = onePassStabilizer;
        }
        int radius = 15;
        double trim_ratio = 0.1;
        bool incl_constr = false;
        stabilizer->setFrameSource(source);
        stabilizer->setMotionEstimator(motionEstBuilder);
        stabilizer->setRadius(radius);
        stabilizer->setTrimRatio(trim_ratio);
        stabilizer->setCorrectionForInclusion(incl_constr);
        stabilizer->setBorderMode(BORDER_REPLICATE);
        stabilizedFrames.reset(dynamic_cast<IFrameSource *>(stabilizer));


        VideoWriter writer;
        Mat stabilizedFrame;
        int nframes = 0;
        double outputFps = 25;
        while (!(stabilizedFrame = stabilizedFrames->nextFrame()).empty()) {
            nframes++;
            if (!writer.isOpened())
                writer.open(output, VideoWriter::fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D'), outputFps,
                            stabilizedFrame.size());
            writer << stabilizedFrame;
            imshow("stabilizedFrame", stabilizedFrame);
            char key = static_cast<char>(waitKey(3));
            if (key == 27) {
                cout << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << "processed frames: " << nframes << endl;
        cout << "finished " << endl;


//        processing(stabilizedFrames, outputPath);
    }
    catch (const exception &e) {
        cout << "error: " << e.what() << endl;
        stabilizedFrames.release();
        return ;
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(inputPath, input);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(outputPath, output);
    stabilizedFrames.release();

}
```